# Power Automate: how to catch which column was updated in Dataverse Connector

Tags: row, power-automate, connector, dataverse

I'm starting from a "When a row is added, modified or deleted" connector, i'm passing in a switch connector that controls if the row is added, modified or deleted.

I'm then using the mail node to notify myself if a row is added, modified or deleted, in the case a row is added i have to include in the mail which fields of that row have been modified.

I can't find if this control is possible (check the row and compare it with the pre-modified version) and how to do it.

[This is the embrional flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cZ6t.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please note that i need to be able to see what row updated after the Dataverse CRUD connector triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you for getting specific modifications: https://carldesouza.com/power-automate-dataverse-adding-scope-for-field-changes/

In the trigger node, if you click "Show advanced options", you'll see a textbox labeled "Select columns". If you enter any field name in that box, the cloud flow won't trigger unless one of those fields is modified. Hovering over the textbox shows you an explanation of what it does.

Comment: I just logged in today, i solved this some time ago and that's exactly how i did it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As requested i'll try to be more detailed.

Please note that this is a POWER AUTOMATE FLOW so there is almost no code.

The CRUD connector takes 3 arguments:

-Change type (When an item is Added, Modified or Deleted)
-The table name (It's the Dataverse table name)
-The scope (Business Unit)

So i need to know if (for example in the output of this connector) there is a variable or other connector that contains which column changed and caused the trigger)

It's a question about the output or possible connectors related to the Dataverse CRUD node so there is NO CODE involved and no more "after-issue" flow specification needed to understand my request

Comment: Please put this info into the questions itself. It's much more easier to answer when all info is placed in the single place.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to create a new field that keeps the current value of the original  field and use trigger conditions to make your flow run only when those two fields don't match, meaning that the original field is updated and that its value has changed.